# How to grep in ex command output?

Tags: vimscript

How does one search for a pattern in ex command output? For example, how to search for a file name pattern in the output of `:scriptnames` command? In the help for all flavours of `grep` and `vimgrep` there is only `{file}` as a place where to perform search.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do:

`:redir => scriptn | sil exe 'scriptnames' | redir end | echo(system('grep pattern',scriptn))`

What it does:

```
:redir => scriptn                      "redirect following output to variable scriptn
:sil exe 'scriptnames'                 "silently execute scriptnames
:redir end                             "end the redirection
:echo(system('grep pattern',scriptn))  "echo the call of grep witht that input with the pattern `pattern`
```

Answer (score 19):

The [`:filter`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#:filter) command is a simple, one-line approach to this:

```
:filter /indent/ scriptnames
```

This would show *only* lines matching the pattern `indent` from the output of the `:scriptnames` command.

Unusually, `:filter` does **not** observe either `'ignorecase'` or `'smartcase'` and will always search in a case-**sensitive** manner. To override this, prepend `\c` to your search pattern, e.g.:

```
:filter /\cindent/ scriptnames
```

See [`:h \c`](https://vimhelp.org/pattern.txt.html#%2Fignorecase) for more info.

---

I see `:redir`-oriented solutions to questions like these often, which are fine and offer a lot of power and options, but I feel they're a bit overkill when more often than not, you just need to quickly check if something is there. `:filter` is convenient to use in the moment and dead simple.

Comment: this is cleaner and more concise.

Comment: Indeed, this should be the accepted answer. (Learned a lot from edi9999's answer though, hence the upvote.)

Comment: How do I filter in a case-insensitive manner?

Comment: @jdhao Great question! For some reason, `filter` doesn't observe `'ignorecase'` like other pattern-using commands. You can however force it by prepending `\c` to your pattern, like so: `:filter /\cindent/ scriptnames`. See also `:h \c`.

Comment: @ZeroKnight Thanks for your prompt reply. I have also figured out `\c` is need to search case-insensitively.

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to grab the output of `scriptnames` and put it into a buffer.

You can use `:redir` for that:

```
:redir @a       " redirect output of following ex commands to register a
:scriptnames    " press G to get to the end of the output if it's too long
:redir END      " end the redirection
:vnew           " new buffer in vertical window
:put a          " put content of register
/pattern        " search for 'pattern'
```

That said, a `:scriptname` output that's too long to be scanned with your own eyes may be a symptom of deeper problems.

Comment: Agree with your last sentence.  If the output is that long, the filtering should be done directly from the command line, not from within ex.

Comment: Sorry, don't see what you mean about too long list. E.g. syntastic has in that list 10 files, nerdtree another 13 files, etc.

Comment: If the output of your `:scriptnames` is longer than Magna Carta you might consider installing Tim Pope's [scriptease](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease).  It provides a function `:Scriptnames` that puts all that junk in a quickfix list. There you can search it to your heart's content, save it to a file, or go to the corresponding scripts.

Comment: @AlBerger, a list too long means too many plugins and/or plugins too large or poorly written. 13 files for a single plugin is way too much.

Comment: Are you suggesting that `NERDTree` should put all its functions in a single file, in order to keep the output of `:scriptnames` short?  Would that make it a better written plugin?