# How to search the output of vim command line commands like `:ls`, `:browse oldfiles`

Tags: vimrc, search, quickfix

Back from emacs recently, in emacs I can list all the existing buffers in a emacs buffer, where I can do search, delete or jumping etc.

In Vim, if I type `:browse oldfiles`, a long list may be returned below the command line buffer and I can only move the buffer up&down or just a number to jump to corresponding file.

It will be convenient, if I can search the long list given by `:browse oldfiles`, `:ls` or `:tselect` etc.
I know that `redir` can be used in my case, but it's a bit annoying when you have to do it every time.

I'm wondering if there's a more vim-way to handle this scenario such as `quickfix windows`.

Comment: See [How to grep in ex command output?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/5205/18609) for possible answers to this question. In particular, the answer using `:filter` might be interesting for this specific case.

Comment: @filbranden I think `:filter` is not capable for all the `{command}` after reading `help :filter`. So I try `:filter /xx/ tselect`, and it doesn't work.